# repair postgresql installation in ubuntu - following ALTER SYSTEM

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm running postgresql 9.4 on Ubuntu 14.4.

I made some changes to the configuration file using ALTER SYSTEM through pgadmin (connected remotely).  I then tried to do a restart on the service -> this gave me errors.  Then I tried to install postgres-xc so that I could use the pg_ctl command.  I had trouble getting this to work and so I removed postgres-xc via apt-get remove and did a reboot of the linux box in the hope it would system restart of postgresql.  The service is not running and I cannot start it.  I'm worried that I've done something to corrupt my postgres installation.

What are my options here?  This system holds a live database with quite a bit of data in it - it's in development so no pg_dump has been created.

How can I verify that postgresql is still installed?
When I run:
`/etc/init.d/postgresql start`
I get no response, so I run:

```
ps
```

And there is no postgres service running.

Should I purge the postgresql installation and resinstall it?  Then how would I point it to the existing database?

It isn't clear to me why installing and then removing postgres-xc would impact on the postgres installation.  Could it be that my changes to the configuration file has caused a problem?  How would I find out?

Thanks in advance.

GPC

UPDATE:
I tried running the following command to test the installation:

`postgres -D /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/ --datanode`

I get the following error:

`LOG:  unrecognized configuration parameter "unix_socket_directories" in file "/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf" line 68
LOG:  unrecognized configuration parameter "dynamic_shared_memory_type" in file "/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf" line 130
FATAL:  configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf" contains errors`

Then I try the same command on my actual data folder:
`postgres -D /data/main/ --datanode`

With the following error:
`postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/data/main/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory`

Within the `/data/main/` folder there is only a single config file called `postgresql.auto.conf` that only contains the settings that I changed using `ALTER SYSTEM SET` commands:

`shared_buffers = '963704'
effective_cache_size = '2891112'
checkpoint_segments = '10'
work_mem = '8192'`

UPDATE 2:
I investigated the `/usr/share/postgresql-common/` folder.  This only has a single directory `pgdg` which contains a single file `apt.postgresql.org.asc`.  This doesn't seem right.  There is another folder `postgres-xc` which looks more like an installation of postgres.  Am I missing something here?

I tried issuing the following command:
`sudo service postgres-xc start`

and got the following errors:

`* Starting Postgres-XC datanode                                                                                     pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
                                                                                                              [ OK ]
 * Starting Postgres-XC coordinator                                                                                  pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
                                                                                                              [ OK ]
 * Starting Postgres-XC gtm                                                                                          gtm_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
gtm_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.`

Comment: "this gave me errors", *what errors*?

Comment: I can't recall and I'm further down the rabbit hole from that point.  But basically I wasn't able to restart the service at that time.

Comment: Well, you should make the postgresql service log to a file, then try to start it. You should be able to figure out the problem from it.

Comment: Thanks meskobalazs - can you please point me in the direction of how to do that?  cheers

Comment: For example: `service postgresql start >> /var/log/postgresql.log`

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and the output logfile is empty.  This appears to simply pipe the response from the command which is empty.

Comment: Then there is a problem with the postgresql service. Try to run the binary directly. You should check out the command line parameters in the man page first, though.

Comment: Thanks.  So I switched to postgres user and ran:  `postgres -D /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/ --datanode` and I get the following error `LOG:  unrecognized configuration parameter "unix_socket_directories" in file "/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf" line 68
LOG:  unrecognized configuration parameter "dynamic_shared_memory_type" in file "/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf" line 130
FATAL:  configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf" contains errors`

Comment: My data folder is actually /data/main , but this folder only contains a postgresql.auto.conf, not a postgresql.conf file...

Comment: The Ubuntu bug that advises users to install `postgres-xc` when they try to use `pg_ctl` infuriates me. It's so user-hostile, dangerously broken, and they just haven't seemed to care. It looks like it's fixed in the latest, now, but not in stable. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/command-not-found/+bug/1384864

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for your comment.  I wish I had have known about that bug!  Do you have any insight into recovering my system from here?  I've updated my original post with some more detail.

Comment: Craig if I did an apt-get purge of my installation, is it possible to install fresh and point it at my database raw files that are stored in `/data/main` with the tablespace in `/data/hb_tablespace/` ?  At the moment I can't start the database service so can't progress